# Smith Normal Form of polynomial matrix

Tags: smith-normal-form

Here is a question on finding the Smith Normal Form of a polynomial matrix [Smith normal form of a polynomial matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222833/smith-normal-form-of-a-polynomial-matrix?rq=1)

I am wondering why my method is wrong here:

$\begin{bmatrix}
x^2&x-1\\
x&x^2
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
x&x^2\\
x^2&x-1
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
x&0\\
x^2&-x^3(x-1)
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
x&0\\
0&-x^3(x-1)
\end{bmatrix}$

Obviously $x|-x^3(x-1)$. So why is this wrong?

The answer should be
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&x^4-x^2+x
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: there is a gcd for polynomials, and the gcd of your four polynomials is $1.$  For instance $\gcd(x^2, x-1) = 1,$  with Bezout relation  $$  \left(   x^{2}  \right)  \left( 1  \right)  -  \left(   x  - 1 \right)  \left(   x  + 1 \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$  You should make position (1,1)  into a $1$  as quickly as possible. After that, the (1,2) position and the (2,1)  can be set to zero easily

Comment: The third matrix, right bottom entry is incorrect. After multiplying $x$  on the first column, subtracting from the second column, the entry is $x-1-x^3$. I am not sure where you obtained $-x^3(x-1)$