# A bit of trouble computing the Smith normal form of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, smith-normal-form

I am trying to diagonalize the following $\lambda-$matrix:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 -\lambda -16 & -17 & 87 & -108 \\
 8 & 9-\lambda  & -42 & 54 \\
 -3 & -3 & 16-\lambda  & -18 \\
 -1 & -1 & 6 & -\lambda -8 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I am allowed to do the following:

> [image]
>
> [image]

But this is the best I could come up to:

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \lambda -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1-\lambda  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -3 \lambda  & 2-2 \lambda  \\
 -3 \lambda  & 0 & 3 & 1-\lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Are there tricks or heuristics to do that? The final result must be a matrix with only polynomials in the diagonal, [I've been trying for hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4GPT.png) but still can't make it.

Comment: What is the meaning of a $\lambda$ matrix?

Comment: Why $\lambda$-matrix? There is no $\lambda$. Please don't use pictures.

Comment: The phrasing is odd to me, but you seem to be just describing Gaussian elimination

Comment: @FShrike Matrix with polynomial entries. Yes, it's similar to Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Fixed.

Comment: I obtain indeed a diagonal matrix with entries $(-t+1,-t-2,\rho_1,\rho_2)$ with $\rho_i$ root of $x^2+x(t+5)-2t+50=0$, but this is the symbolic Jordan form. Which normal form do you have to compute? And - please don't use pictures.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, I want this for the Jordan normal form. I am following [Kurosh's book](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~grigor/kurosh-higher-algebra.pdf) on Algebra. It seems the elements that appear in the diagonal are used to compute de Jordan canonical form.

Comment: Surely this is a Smith Normal Form question. If what you have done so far is correct then I think it crunches out to $1,1, \lambda-1, (\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+2)$. (But I may have made a mistake in the sums.)

Comment: This question explains how to do it, although the example is a bit trivial https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222833/smith-normal-form-of-a-polynomial-matrix?rq=1

Comment: @ancientmathematician This is really really nice and it seems this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If you know the theory I would suggest you to use SageMath or Macaulay2
For SageMath:(If you use $x$ instead of $\lambda$ it would be easier.)

var('x')

M=Matrix([[first row],[second row],....,[last row]])

M.smith_form()

This should give you the smith form.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you going.

Pre-mutiply the matrix with:

$$ \Phi= \begin{bmatrix}1\\
 & 1\\
 &  & 1\\
 &  & -1 & \frac{\lambda^{2}-8\lambda+7}{-9(2\lambda+1)}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\
 & 1\\
 & -1 & \frac{\lambda+8}{-8}\\
 & -1 &  & \frac{\lambda+8}{-8}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\
-1 & \frac{\lambda+16}{-8}\\
-1 &  & \frac{\lambda+16}{3}\\
-1 &  &  & \frac{\lambda+16}{1}
\end{bmatrix}$$

and you will get an upper triangular matrix.

Then post multiply with

$$ \Psi=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
 & \frac{\lambda+16}{17}\\
 &  & \frac{\lambda+16}{-87}\\
 &  &  & \frac{\lambda+16}{108}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\
 & 1 & -1 & -1\\
 &  & \frac{29\left(\lambda^{2}+7\lambda-8\right)}{34\left(4-7\lambda\right)}\\
 &  &  & \frac{2\left(\lambda^{2}+7\lambda-8\right)}{-17\lambda}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\
 & 1\\
 &  & 1 & -1\\
 &  &  & \frac{\lambda\left(7-\lambda\right)}{2\left(7\lambda-4\right)}
\end{bmatrix} $$

Then with ${\rm A}=\begin{bmatrix}-\left(\lambda+16\right) & -17 & 87 & -108\\
8 & 9-\lambda & -42 & 54\\
-3 & -3 & 16-\lambda & -18\\
-1 & -1 & 6 & -\left(\lambda+8\right)
\end{bmatrix}$ you have the diagonalization as follows:

$$ \mathrm{D} = \Phi{\rm A}\Psi=\begin{bmatrix}\ddots\\
 & \ddots\\
 &  & \ddots\\
 &  &  & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}  $$

The matrices are found in stages trying to make each column under the *i*-th diagonal zero.

The general form for the *i*-th column is (here $k=i+1 \ldots n$)

$$\small \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & \frac{A_{ii}}{A_{ki}} & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & \frac{A_{ii}}{A_{ni}}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{1i} & A_{1k} & A_{1n}\\
0 & A_{ii} & A_{ik} & A_{in}\\
0 & A_{ki} & A_{kk} & A_{kn}\\
0 & A_{ni} & A_{nk} & A_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{1i} & A_{1k} & A_{1n}\\
0 & A_{ii} & A_{ik} & A_{in}\\
0 & 0 & \frac{A_{ii}}{A_{ki}}A_{kk}-A_{ik} & \frac{A_{ii}}{A_{ki}}A_{kn}-A_{in}\\
0 & 0 & \frac{A_{ii}}{A_{ni}}A_{nk}-A_{ik} & \frac{A_{ii}}{A_{ni}}A_{nn}-A_{in}
\end{bmatrix}$$

At least for $\Phi$, and for $\Psi$ I did the exact same thing to $A^\top$. So in the answer, I cheated a bit, because the diagonalization is $ \mathrm{D} = \Phi{\rm A}\Psi^\top $ really. I just decided to present $\Phi^\top$ as $\Phi$ above for simplicity.

Comment: How did you construct those matrices?

Comment: @RedBanana - see edits above.